# data cleaning of list in python

Tags: python, list

I have read in  dvd title descriptions and prices as sentences in a list the title of the dvd starts with [t] like:
`['[t] the little mermaid.','disney fairytale','price of this $5.99', '[t] star wars.','disney fantasy','price $6']`

How can I remove the whole title from the list.. so item that starts with [t] so the list will only have the description and price.

I tried to use the list.remove but this only removed the [t] and not the dvd titles

Comment: If i got your question correct, I think you want to remove elements starting with ```[t]```. You can do ```[a for a in <list> if not "[t]" in a]```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `startswith`:

```
lst = ['[t] the little mermaid.','disney fairytale','price of this $5.99', '[t] star wars.','disney fantasy','price $6']
print([i for i in lst if not i.startswith('[t] ')])
```

Output:

```
['disney fairytale', 'price of this $5.99', 'disney fantasy', 'price $6']
```